# Removing specific keys from an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, key

Given an array of elements like ["a","r","g"] and an object, I am trying to remove the key/value pairs where the keys are elements of the array.

```js
function shorten(arr, obj) {
  
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);          //make an array of the object's keys
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)   //loop for original array (arr) 
      for(var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++)  //loop for "keys" array
          if(arr[i] === obj[keys[j]])           //check for array element matches
              delete obj[keys[j]];                  //delete the matches from object
  return obj;                           //return the new object
    
}

 var arrA = ['a','r', 'g'];
 var oB = {a: 4, u: 1, r: 2, h: 87, g: 4};
 console.log(shorten(arrA,oB))         //I keep getting the original object
                                       //The function isn't shortening things
```

```
//desired output is:

{u: 1, h: 87}
```

To anyone that reads this and can help me out, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9):

The reason your code isn't working is it's comparing the **value** of the property with the property's name (`a` with `4`, etc.)

Assuming you really want to delete the properties listed in the array, which is what you said but not what your desired output suggests, the code can be a **lot** simpler, since `delete` is a no-op if the object doesn't have the property:

```js
function shorten(arr, obj) {
  arr.forEach(function(key) {
    delete obj[key];
  });
  return obj;
}

var arrA = ['a','r', 'g'];
var oB = {a: 4, u: 1, r: 2, h: 87, g: 4};
console.log(shorten(arrA, oB));
```

---

Side note: It usually doesn't matter, but it's worth noting that using `delete` on an object on some JavaScript engines makes subsequent property lookup operations on that object much slower. Engines are optimized to handle properties being *added* and updated, but not removed. When a property is removed, it disables the optimizations some JavaScript engines do on property lookup. Of course, again, it usually doesn't matter...