# Custom sort/order object array based on keys stored in a string array js

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an `Object Array` (applicants) and a `String Array` (column_order).

I will be displaying the applicants in a table and need to change the order of the columns based on the order of the keys` that match the strings in column order. The order will be the same as the order of the strings in column_order, the non matching keys stay in their normal order at the end of their respective object.

This is hard for me to explain. So I will give some example results to help explain.

```
applicants = [
{applicant_id: 5, recruiter_id: null, resume_cv_id: "null", cover_letter_id: "null", nda_id: null},
{applicant_id: 6, recruiter_id: null, resume_cv_id: "null", cover_letter_id: "null", nda_id: null}]
```

---

First Example Below:
Notice how I want the recruiter_id to be the first key pair in each object in the array.

Then rest there were not mentioned are at the end of the object.

```
column_order = ["recruiter_id"]

result = [
{ recruiter_id: null, applicant_id: 5, resume_cv_id: "null", cover_letter_id: "null", nda_id: null},
{ recruiter_id: null, applicant_id: 6, resume_cv_id: "null", cover_letter_id: "null", nda_id: null}]
```

---

Second Example Below:
Notice how I want the recruiter_id to be the first key pair in each object in the array then followed by the cover_letter_id.

Then rest there were not mentioned are at the end of the object.

```
column_order = ["recruiter_id","cover_letter_id"]

result = [
{recruiter_id: null,cover_letter_id: "null", applicant_id: 5,  resume_cv_id: "null",  nda_id: null},
{recruiter_id: null,cover_letter_id: "null", applicant_id: 6,  resume_cv_id: "null",  nda_id: null}]
```

---

I was thinking to maybe filter out the keys that match and then store them in a temp object array. And then combining it back after the check for matched finished...?

Below is what I have so far. Though its non function to say the least. I was playing with it to see what results I returned.

```
props.data = props.data.filter(function (obj) {
    var temp_obj = {}
    var obj_length = Object.size(obj)
    for (let index = 0; index < obj_length; index++) {

      if (Object.keys(obj)[index] == "asdasda") {
        console.log("This: ", Object.keys(obj)[index])
      }
      else {
        console.log("len",)
        var pair = { AAaa: "Test" };
        temp_obj[Object.size(temp_obj)] = { ...temp_obj[Object.size(temp_obj)], ...pair };

      }
    }

    return temp_obj
  })
```

I am going to try and use this [Removing specific keys from an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42050065/removing-specific-keys-from-an-object) to remove the matching keys and then re-join them back at the start.

I am finding this to be very confusing and hard to work out. Could someone please assist me with giving me the code to handle this problem.

Comment: Fixed it. The objects in the array should all be the same order.

Comment: Ok, this last edit makes **a lot** more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon your description, the approach below pulls out the column names that are not in the `column_order`, and concatenates those to the `column_order` array. This provides an array of column names in the correct order.

Then, the task becomes looping over the actual `applicants` data and the `sortedColumns` in order to reconstruct the `applicants` in the `newOrder`.

```js
// Given:
const applicants = [{applicant_id: 5, recruiter_id: null, resume_cv_id: "null", cover_letter_id: "null", nda_id: null},
{applicant_id: 6, recruiter_id: null, resume_cv_id: "null", cover_letter_id: "null", nda_id: null}];

const column_order = ['applicant_id', 'resume_cv_id'];

// Sort Columns
const sortedColumns = column_order.concat(
  Object.keys(applicants[0])
  .filter(k => k !== column_order[0] && k !== column_order[1])
);

// Create new applicants in correct column order
const newOrder = applicants.map(a => {
  let row = {};
  sortedColumns.forEach(c => row[c] = a[c]);
  return row;
});

console.log(newOrder);
```

Answer (score 1):

I could be off here by thinking about this  problem a different way, but it seems to me that you ultimately want the order of the table headers/columns to be the goal. If that's the case, then we don't necessarily need to mutate the data itself.

This is answer could be reflective of a data-binding solution, such as Vuejs or creating the table on the fly (i.e. creating table elements in a loop of the data).

Set the initial data - data array and array of keys to rearrange.

Set the header names based on the first object in the array, assuming they are all the same: `const headers = Object.keys(applicants[0]);`

Set the rearranged headers with a function which reverses the keys array so the order reflects the keys array order and then sorts the array for each item in the keys array.

```js
const applicants =[{applicant_id: 5, recruiter_id: null, resume_cv_id: "null", cover_letter_id: "null", nda_id: null},
{applicant_id: 5, recruiter_id: null, resume_cv_id: "null", cover_letter_id: "null", nda_id: null}];
const column_order = ["recruiter_id","cover_letter_id"];
const defaultHeaders = Object.keys(applicants[0]);
const mappedHeaders = mapHeaders(defaultHeaders, column_order);

function mapHeaders(arrayToMap, keysToFront) {
    let mapped = [...arrayToMap]; // Clone the array
  
  keysToFront.reverse()
    .forEach((x, i) => {
        mapped.sort((a,b) => (b === x) ? 1 : -1 );
  });
  
  return mapped;
};

console.log('defaultHeaders', defaultHeaders);
console.log('mappedHeaders', mappedHeaders);
```